# Ball and urn with dice problem

Tags: probability

I had the following question on my exam and was stuck on it; it has been bothering me for a bit.

An urn contains 4 white and 4 red balls. A fair die is rolled and the number that appears is the number of balls taken out of the urn at random. Let $X$ be the number of red balls taken. Find $P(X\ge2)$

My attempt

$X $~ Hyp($N,n,M$)

$P(X\ge2) = 1 - P(X=1) - P(X=0)$

For a hypergeometric random variable we have
$P(X=k)$= $\frac {{M\choose k} {N-M\choose n-k}}{N\choose n}$
Where $N$ is the population size, $M$ is the number of success states in the population, $n$ is the number of draws, and $k$ is the number of successes.

In this case $N$ is $8$, $M$  is $4$ and $1\le n \le 6$. I am having trouble dealing with $n$ since it is dependent on the number that is rolled on the die and not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  you have $\frac 16$ chance that $n$ is each of $1,2,3,4,5,6$. So you want $\frac 16[P(X \ge 2|n=1)+P(X \ge 2|n=2)+P(X \ge 2|n=3)+P(X \ge 2|n=4)+P(X \ge 2|n=5)+P(X \ge 2|n=6)]$

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. Just a lot of calculations :)

Comment: Well, the first one is easy.  $P(X\ge 2|n=1)=0$  The others are harder.